# Arguments passed to executable in script

Tags: powershell

I am wondering why one method works but the other does not

Not sure what to try

```
1.

$syspinEXE = "Z:\syspin.exe"
$programDataPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
&$syspinEXE "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Word 2016.lnk" 5386


2.

$syspinEXE = "Z:\syspin.exe"
$programDataPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
&$syspinEXE "$programDataPath","Word 2016.lnk" -join "\" 5386
```

I am wondering why the first snippet works but the second snippet does not. I believe they should both work, but this is obviously not true.

Comment: Could you please remove the double quotes from `"$programDataPath"` and try again? :)

Comment: Put `"$programDataPath","Word 2016.lnk" -join "\"` in parentheses, otherwise `-join` and `"\"` will be interpreted as a parameter name and a separate argument to `&`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you so much! Your solution worked. I am new to scripting with PowerShell and am doing my best to learn. Would you mind explaining why parentheses works here? I am not sure how they effect the program flow. Preliminary thanks for your explanation.

Comment: The `( )` causes the expression within them to be evaluated first before being passed to the command. (Otherwise, as noted, it will be seen as separate parameters.)

Comment: @Fennec: The double quotes are certainly not necessary, but removing them makes no difference here.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
$startMenuPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::CommonStartMenu)
Get-ChildItem $startMenuPath -Filter "Word 2*" -Recurse |
  Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object {
    & $_.FullName 5386
  }
```